# Use LIMIT with Spring Data and Postgres

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data

I'm facing a problem with limiting query results using Spring Data (native query) and Postgres.

In Postgres is possible to use LIMIT keyword with a integer (LIMIT 50 for getting the first 50 results) or with a string (LIMIT ALL to get all the results). I'm trying to use the same query that handles both situations.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * 
FROM tableA 
WHERE columnA = :value 
LIMIT :size", nativeQuery = true)
TableA findByColumnA(@Param("columnA") String columnA, @Param("size") String size);
```

The problem is that I'm getting this exception:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: argument of LIMIT must be type bigint, not type character varying
```

I understand the error, if I change the type of variable size to int, the query works with no problem, but I can't pass the value 'ALL' to the query.

Anybody have a solution for using a string in the limit clause?

PS: I'm using hibernate.

EDIT: Just to clarify, I know that I could have a second method without the limit clause. I just want to know if what I want it's possible.

Comment: You'll have to design around it, for example by passing `Integer.MAX_VALUE` instead of `ALL`. Although I'd say the whole idea of having a `LIMIT` there is dubious design.

Comment: I don't agree to pass the MAX_VALUE. It's just a "random" number that hide the core problem. Why it's a dubious design?

Comment: There's nothing *random* about `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, au contraire, it's even consistent across different computer architectures. However design-wise I'd say that having the caller pass a custom limit isn't something the caller should be doing. Especially since you're not even trying to do paging as there's no offset.

Comment: We are talking about a query that is used for batch processing so it makes sense that I have a limit for the query. The only thing that is questionable is if it should be one query or two queries (one with limit clause and other without it).

Answer (score 4):

`LIMIT NULL` will retrieve all the data as well.

You can try `NULLIF` after `LIMIT`. So, if your limit value is `null` you can send as a parameter the value `-1`. For example:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * 
FROM tableA 
WHERE columnA = :value 
LIMIT NULLIF(:size, -1)", nativeQuery = true)
TableA findByColumnA(@Param("columnA") String columnA, @Param("size") Integer size);
```

And:

```
Integer limit = param == null ? -1 : param;    
findByColumnA("string", limit)
```

Documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF

Answer (score 0):

Change `@Param("size") String size` to `@Param("size") Long size` and create another method for this.

If you're using `LIMIT` in your query, you probably want to limit the result set. If you don't want to limit use `findBy...` without pagination and do the math inside your service layer.

This will make your code clean.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but at the moment I have already implement what you said. What I want to know if it is possible to do what I describe.